# Convert Access desktop application to Web based

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

We have an SQL Express database with an Access 2003 front end which we can convert to Access 2010 or 2013. The database has a lot of forms, queries & tables & complex VBA code.

What is the procedure to make this web enabled so a limited number of our customers can logon and update information in the forms

Will it require VBA coding from scratch, some minor changes or I don't need to change the VBA code at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should consider posting this question on StackOverflow for better results.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any way to move this or I will have to copy and paste there?